# Why did Misty leave the Pokemon anime?

Tags: pokemon

I remember watching the Pokemon anime when I was a kid, and I was absolutely obsessed with Ash, Brock, Misty, and Pikachu. I remember when Brock left, and then there was Tracy, and then Brock came back. After a while, I stopped watching, but then resumed a few years later, to see that both Brock and Misty were gone, and they were replaced with May and Max (I think this is correct).

I must have missed what happened to Misty and Brock during my brief absence from the Pokemon franchise. I'll leave Brock for another question (or maybe bonus points if you know about what happened to him too), but what happened to Misty? What was her reason for leaving the original team? Separate from that reason, what was the executive reason for deleting Misty? For example, when the writing staff got rid of Brock the first time, they said it was due to his flirtatious manner, and were worried he would not be well received. Was there any reason similar to this for Misty's disappearance? Could she ever return, like Brock did?

Comment: i thought she have to take over her family gym for her sisters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Misty left at the end of the original Pokemon series because her sisters won the lottery and wanted to travel around the world, so they asked Misty to stay at the gym to be the gym leader. This is in episode 273 of the anime. Of course, Misty didn't want to and wanted to travel more with Ash, but eventually she left to become the gym leader after a battle with a nasty kid along with Ash, who was showing signs of unwillingness (which made her feel a tad bit better).

As for Brock, he needed to go home and visit his family, and he pretended he forgot about this until the very last minute. So Brock, Misty and Ash each went back to their home and that was the end of the little team. Then, when Ash got home, Gary left as well, so he got bored and decided to go to Hoen where he meets Max, May, and reunited with Brock.

P.S. it was at the end of the anime too so they needed to find a reason to finish the series.